# How to keep listening in FP?

Tags: scala, haskell

I want to use Kafka for sending messages between microservices.

Kafka uses publish subscribe mechanism, that it is mean, a producer produces messages, kafka receives it and subscribes to consumers. Consumers always listen to an events for incoming messages and react accordingly.

My question is, how to build a system with functional programming language(scala, haskell), for listening incoming events?

It is like a http server, that is listening for incoming requests.

I think, it needs an `IO Monad` because of the side effects, that is going the happen.
And how to keep it always running? With a simple look?

Comment: This may be a matter of discretion. Scala is hybrid in nature so its really up to you to keep referentially transparent code separate from side effecting code – think IO Monads in Haskell. While the implementational details are quite generic based on your question, I'd suggest using Akka streams – wherein your sources can be exposed via an IO interface and consumers – RT or not, can act upon the "output" of the Source. The other end of the side effects can be accomplished using Sink's – another concept Akka streams introduces. Its really up to you to keep the code "in-between" RT.

Comment: You could implement the Polling Consumer pattern. [Here's an article that shows how to do that in Haskell](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/06/28/pure-times-in-haskell).

Comment: If you interested to go with Scala you can have a look to this blog: https://medium.com/dive-in-scala/communicating-with-kafka-using-akka-actors-ce4af02482c6 and this github repository: https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client

Comment: Take a look at this implementation: https://github.com/monix/monix-kafka (monix Task is an implementation of IO Monad, but the key concept is `Observable`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scala, but in Haskell the answer is, exactly like you would in an imperative language, but in the IO monad.

There may be systems like Functional Reactive Programming that let you write listeners in a functional way, but ultimately they're declarative languages for generating an imperative program, and under the hood they're going to be imperative.

Some people consider Haskell to be their favorite imperative language! The idea is not that Haskell has no side effects, but that the type system makes it explicitly clear where they occur and in what order.